# Why isn't my radio button transparent?

Tags: delphi, radio-button, transparency

I want to let a group box control the background color for a radio button, but the radio button is not transparent.  Themes are enabled and I have parentbackground set to true for the radiobutton.

This is what I get:

[image: Radiobutton is not transparent]

I'd like to have the blue gradient show through the radiobutton and not use any color for the background of the radiobutton.

I'm calling this method, drawing on the group box with GDI+:

```
procedure TMyRadio.PaintBackground(AParentColor : TColor; Graphics: IGPGraphics);
var
  ExpandedRect : TGPRect;
  Path : IGPGraphicsPath;
  GradientBrush : IGPPathGradientBrush;
  SurroundColors : array[0..0] of TGPColor;
begin

  ExpandedRect := TGPRect.Create(ExpandBorder(BoundsRect, 10));
  Path := TGPGraphicsPath.Create;
  Path.AddRectangle(ExpandedRect);
  GradientBrush :=  TGPPathGradientBrush.Create(Path);

  GradientBrush.CenterColor := TGPColor.Create(255,
                                               GetRValue(ColorToRGB(BackgroundColor)),
                                               GetGValue(ColorToRGB(BackgroundColor)),
                                               GetBValue(ColorToRGB(BackgroundColor))
                                               );

  SurroundColors[0].Initialize(0,
                               GetRValue(ColorToRGB(AParentColor)),
                               GetGValue(ColorToRGB(AParentColor)),
                               GetBValue(ColorToRGB(AParentColor))
                               );

  GradientBrush.SetSurroundColors(SurroundColors);
  Graphics.FillRectangle(GradientBrush, ExpandedRect);

end;
```

from the overridden paint function the group box that the radio button is in and it doesn't show through the radio button control.  I'm not setting the color of the radiobutton anywhere else and I've checked to see that `ParentBackground = true` when this is being ran.

Comment: Is DoubleBuffering enabled, eg `DoubleBuffered := True`? Sometimes this can cause graphical problems with controls. If it is, set it to false either by code or from the parent control in the Object Inspector.

Comment: @blobby, I've tried it both ways.  I also tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461793/is-there-a-way-to-make-tradiobutton-be-transparent and ran it without themes (on terminal server) and it looked awful. So I may just go with a solid color anyway.

Comment: I think this might be one of those cases where 3rd party components may be more suitable for what you were trying to do.

Comment: BoundsRect should refer to the bounding rectangle of the radio group if PaintBackground is a method of the radio group. But from the picture you've posted it looks like the rectangle is calculated based on the bounding rectangle of the radio button. You're sure you've overridden the Paint of the group box, and not the radio button?

Comment: @Blobby I actually tried some super ancient (Delphi 3) 3rd party control from Torry's and it actually works!

Comment: @PeterTurner you should post it up here for others to see ;)

Comment: I used [Dream Controls](http://www.torry.net/quicksearchd.php?String=transparent+radio&Title=No) with minor modifications for XE2

Comment: +1 for posting, I have used Torry's before and as you said some of the stuff on there is ancient, as far back and maybe even further then 1996!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an inconsistency between the picture posted in the question, and the code and the description of the code (see my comment on the question). The background of the group box should be painted in the paint cycle of the group box. The below works (tested with XE2, the radio buttons are transparent):

```
type
  TMyGroupBox = class(TGroupBox)
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
    procedure PaintBackground(AParentColor : TColor; Graphics: IGPGraphics);
  end;

  ..

procedure TMyGroupBox.Paint;
var
  G: IGPGraphics;
begin
  inherited;
  G := TGPGraphics.Create(Canvas.Handle);
  PaintBackground(clYellow, G);
end;

procedure TMyGroupBox.PaintBackground(AParentColor: TColor; Graphics: IGPGraphics);
var
  ..
begin
  // Same as in the question. Of course the rectangle should be calculated
  // based on the positions of radio button...
  ..
```

---

The below is an example how this could be incorporated with styles (which I was wondering if it would be easy):

```
uses
  .., gdiplus;

type
  TGroupBoxStyleHook = class(vcl.stdctrls.TGroupBoxStyleHook)
  strict protected
    procedure PaintBackground(Canvas: TCanvas); override;
  end;

  TGroupBox = class(vcl.stdctrls.TGroupBox)
  private
    FButtonSize: Integer;
    FGradientMargin: Integer;
    function GetButtonSize: Integer;
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
    procedure PaintBackground(AParentColor: TColor; Graphics: IGPGraphics);
    procedure CMWininichange(var Message: TMessage); message CM_WININICHANGE;
    property ButtonSize: Integer read GetButtonSize;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    property GradientMargin: Integer
        read FGradientMargin write FGradientMargin default 10;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    GroupBox1: TGroupBox;
    RadioButton1: TRadioButton;
    RadioButton2: TRadioButton;
    Button1: TButton;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  themes, uxtheme;

{$R *.dfm}


{ TGroupBoxStyleHook }

procedure TGroupBoxStyleHook.PaintBackground(Canvas: TCanvas);
var
  G: IGPGraphics;
begin
  inherited;
  G := TGPGraphics.Create(Canvas.Handle);
  (Control as TGroupBox).PaintBackground(clYellow, G);
end;


{ TGroupBox }

constructor TGroupBox.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FGradientMargin := 10;
  TCustomStyleEngine.RegisterStyleHook(TCustomGroupBox, TGroupBoxStyleHook);
end;

procedure TGroupBox.CMWininichange(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  FButtonSize := 0;
  inherited;
end;

function TGroupBox.GetButtonSize: Integer;
var
  Size: TSize;
begin
  Result := FButtonSize;
  if StyleServices.Enabled and (Result = 0) then begin
    TStyleManager.SystemStyle.GetElementSize(0,
        TStyleManager.SystemStyle.GetElementDetails(tbRadioButtonCheckedNormal),
        TRect.Empty, esActual, Size);
    FButtonSize := Size.cx;
    Result := FButtonSize;
  end;
end;


procedure TGroupBox.PaintBackground(AParentColor: TColor; Graphics: IGPGraphics);
const
  BackGroundColor = clBlue;
var
  R: TRect;
  i: Integer;

  ExpandedRect : TGPRect;
  Path : IGPGraphicsPath;
  GradientBrush : IGPPathGradientBrush;
  SurroundColors : array[0..0] of TGPColor;
begin
  for i := 0 to ControlCount - 1 do begin
    if Controls[i] is TRadioButton then begin

      // Don't know what ExpandBorder is.
      //  ExpandedRect := TGPRect.Create(ExpandBorder(BoundsRect, 10));
      R := Controls[i].BoundsRect;
      R.Inflate(GradientMargin, GradientMargin);
      R.Right := R.Left + 2 * GradientMargin + ButtonSize;
      ExpandedRect := TGPRect.Create(R);

      Path := TGPGraphicsPath.Create;
      Path.AddRectangle(ExpandedRect);
      GradientBrush :=  TGPPathGradientBrush.Create(Path);

      GradientBrush.CenterColor := TGPColor.Create(255,
                                         GetRValue(ColorToRGB(BackgroundColor)),
                                         GetGValue(ColorToRGB(BackgroundColor)),
                                         GetBValue(ColorToRGB(BackgroundColor))
                                         );
      SurroundColors[0].Initialize(0,
                                   GetRValue(ColorToRGB(AParentColor)),
                                   GetGValue(ColorToRGB(AParentColor)),
                                   GetBValue(ColorToRGB(AParentColor))
                                   );
      GradientBrush.SetSurroundColors(SurroundColors);
      Graphics.FillRectangle(GradientBrush, ExpandedRect);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TGroupBox.Paint;
var
  G: IGPGraphics;
begin
  //  'Paint' is not called with styles other than the SystemStyle
  inherited;

  // Do not draw the background with no runtime themes (no default transparency)
  if StyleServices.Enabled then begin
    G := TGPGraphics.Create(Canvas.Handle);
    PaintBackground(clRed, G); // I don't notice any effect of color passed here
  end;
end;
```

Looks like:
Default [image: Windows style], Styled [image: Amethyst Kamri style]

Comment: PaintBackground is a member of the RadioButton class.  I can't override the paint function of the radio button can I?

Comment: @Peter - It shouldn't be. You shouldn't override any method of the radio button. As I stated, you should paint the group box in its own paint cycle.

Comment: I don't override any method of the radiobutton.  I only call the PaintBackground function from the group box's paint function, what I posted is me painting the background of the group box in it's on paint function.  I'm in the middle of testing your code though, the problem is probably something 10 miles down preventing runtime themes from working properly.

Comment: No, it didn't it looked exactly like it did in my screenshot, no transparency. I'll try this new stuff with the styles today though.

Comment: @Peter - I'm not sure it will make a difference, it's the same code a bit extended. I suggest you to try with a new project.

Comment: Yeah, I did try on a new project, maybe I didn't have runtime themes enabled.  One thing that I have done (and avoided using some 12 year old code) was to use styleservices.DrawParentBackground, but I won't argue with your screenshots - Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Peter - Thanks and you're welcome. But you certainly don't need to accept until you see it working. Maybe it's some other setting that's different.. who knows?

Comment: Finally got it all working to my liking, thanks a lot for the help again, I changed that esActual to esStretch in the get style details (and passed in the DC of the radio button) because I zoom in and out on these controls an it worked really well.  I also used the SplitRect and CenteredRect functions from types.pas to get the exact rectangle around the radio button in case it was a little taller than expected.